# Cannot print results on a separate lines/new line

Tags: r, line, new-operator

I am a beginner to R so I know this is easy. Can't make results print on a new line after each result.
Problem:

```
`x <- ("This is another way to figures out the decimal value in minutes")
print(x)
time_conv <- function(mins){
    paste((mins / 60),"is",mins,"seconds") 

}
print(time_conv(mins = 1:10))`




`[1] "This is another way to figures out the decimal value in minutes"
 [1] "0.0166666666666667 is 1 seconds" "0.0333333333333333 is 2 seconds"
 [3] "0.05 is 3 seconds"               "0.0666666666666667 is 4 seconds"
 [5] "0.0833333333333333 is 5 seconds" "0.1 is 6 seconds"               
 [7] "0.116666666666667 is 7 seconds"  "0.133333333333333 is 8 seconds" 
 [9] "0.15 is 9 seconds"               "0.166666666666667 is 10 seconds"
```

`

Comment: You may want to consider using the `cat` function instead of print for something like this. Try `cat(time_conv(mins = 1:10), sep = "\n")`

Comment: That worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to print something to the console this way, but this might do the trick:

```r
x <- ("This is another way to figures out the decimal value in minutes")

time_conv <- function(mins){
  paste((mins / 60),"is",mins,"seconds", "\n") 
  
}

writeLines(time_conv(mins = 1:10))
#> 0.0166666666666667 is 1 seconds 
#> 
#> 0.0333333333333333 is 2 seconds 
#> 
#> 0.05 is 3 seconds 
#> 
#> 0.0666666666666667 is 4 seconds 
#> 
#> 0.0833333333333333 is 5 seconds 
#> 
#> 0.1 is 6 seconds 
#> 
#> 0.116666666666667 is 7 seconds 
#> 
#> 0.133333333333333 is 8 seconds 
#> 
#> 0.15 is 9 seconds 
#> 
#> 0.166666666666667 is 10 seconds
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

One way could be like this:

```
time_conv <- function(mins) {
  results <- paste((mins / 60), "is", mins, "seconds")
  for (result in results) {
    print(result)
  }
}

time_conv(mins = 1:10)
```

```
[1] "0.0166666666666667 is 1 seconds"
[1] "0.0333333333333333 is 2 seconds"
[1] "0.05 is 3 seconds"
[1] "0.0666666666666667 is 4 seconds"
[1] "0.0833333333333333 is 5 seconds"
[1] "0.1 is 6 seconds"
[1] "0.116666666666667 is 7 seconds"
[1] "0.133333333333333 is 8 seconds"
[1] "0.15 is 9 seconds"
[1] "0.166666666666667 is 10 seconds"
```